# How to return a value to the left of a table array with VLOOKUP?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I need help searching Column E for value=1 and return the value of column A for the same row. VLOOKUP isn't working because there are many columns being searched and there are several 1's in the lookup, and I couldn't seem to search just 1 column using VLOOKUP. Here's how my spreadsheet looks...

```
   A         B           C            D            E
1 Name     Weight     WeightRank     Height     HeightRank     
2 Mike       170          3           6.3           2
3 Richard    200          1           6.0           3
4 Charles    185          2           7.0           1
```

So I want to search column E for value=1 and return the corresponding value in column A, which in this example would search "HeightRank" for "value=1" and return "Charles"

I tried using `=VLOOKUP(1,E:E,1)` but that returns an error.
I tried using `=VLOOKUP(1,A1:E3,1)` but that returns an error.

Answer (score 4):

`INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,E:E,0))`

VLOOKUP doesn't work here -- it always searches in the first column of your table and returns a value of a column a given number of columns to the right.

The INDEX/MATCH combination is more flexible, letting you just choose the two columns you want. It's also easier to read (you don't have to count columns to see what it does) and it doesn't break if you insert or delete columns in between the ones you're using, which VLOOKUP does.  If you use the trace-formula features, VLOOKUP also falsely implies that all the columns in between are precedents of your resulting formula.  (Can you tell that I don't much like VLOOKUP? I just always use INDEX/MATCH and my life is easier for it.)

The OFFSET solution works but it's volatile, so you'll really bog down your worksheet if many cells depend on the result of your formula.

Answer (score 0):

`MATCH(x,E2:E4,0)` returns the relative position of `x` in the range `E2:E4`.  For example, `MATCH(1,E2:E4,0)` returns 3, because 1 is the value of the third cell in the range `E2:E4`.

`OFFSET(A2,r,c)` returns the cell `r` rows and `c` columns away from `A2`.

Thus you can say `=OFFSET(A2,MATCH(1,E2:E4,0)-1,0)` to return the value from column A corresponding to the cell in column E that contains 1.

Comment: Offset is volatile and will cause the sheet to recalculate every time any value is edited. INDEX() is the far better option.